# Is there a way to execute android commands outside the ../sdk/tools folder?

Tags: android, sdk, command-prompt

When I try to execute android commands on the command line (Windows) outside the tools folder, it doesnt recognize android commands. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your `sdk/tools` folder path to your 
`Computer->Properties->Environment Variables->Path` . Click `Edit` and add a semicolon at the end of the previous record and then paste your `sdk/tools` path.

Comment: Check this link too, you might have done something wrong http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38321/what-do-i-type-in-path-variable-for-adb-server-to-start-from-cmd

Comment: thanks, the link helped. in your answer you should edit that also sdk/plataform-tools should be added to path. also point out that the cmd line should be restarted

Comment: Yeah i said path! I guess that the restart of the command line was a common sense!